# Scrapyd links do not work with HTTPS, just keeps loading and loading

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, scrapy, scrapyd

I have `scrapyd` installed in Ubuntu.

I also have a website with SSL enabled, I need to make request to links like `https://IP_HERE:6800/listjobs.json?project=default` inside my website.

But it looks like `Scrapyd` does not work with HTTPS.

Even if I open link in browser it just keeps loading and loading.

But if I make request using `http://` instead of `https://` it works. But I want it to work with HTTPS.

I thought I need to edit my SSL conf file to work with port `6800`. I did but still its not working.

Here is my SSL config file looks like.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443 *:6800>
    .... and rest of confguration...
```

Comment: Odd, can you paste the spider output when trying to connect to the https website?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida not spider sir ... on 6800 port, I have deployed `Scrapyd`, not `Scrapy` ... and then visiting URL with HTTPS it shows `This site can’t be reached`

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [source code of `scrapyd`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/165797e76caebbadbc7fd4c26ce41d2822b3c4e1/scrapyd/app.py#L39), it uses a [`TCPServer` from Pythons `socketserver` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html). It is not possible to enable SSL in a Python module via the Apache config file.

What you want to use is a HTTPS-to-HTTP proxy, which wraps up `scrapyd`'s HTTP into an HTTPS protocol. You can use Apache for that, see [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) from Digital Ocean or [this blog post](http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/redirect-from-http-to-https-and-viceversa-with-apache-proxypass/).